# Find nested object with lodash

Tags: lodash

I want to get the parentobject of an object with a certain id. In this case I know the groupId and want to get the parent object:

```
const myObject = [
  {
    "myItems": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "group": {
          "groupId": 33,
        },
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "group": {
          "groupId": 44,
        },
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

This does not work:

```
const parentObject= filter(myObject, {[myItems: {groupId: 44}]})
```

Comment: is `{[myItems: {groupId: 44}]}` valid syntax?

Comment: @OliverRadini the console does not complain, how would you write it?

Comment: I get a `SyntaxError` at the `:`. You can have square brackets inside an object for a computed key but that doesn't seem to be what's happening here, do you perhaps mean `{myItems: {groupId: 44}}`?

Comment: @vuvu not sure if this would help, but you could achieve similar functionality without lodash as shown here: https://gist.github.com/dacre-denny/2753e0786c1da1d41d119697aa4c2001

Answer (score 0):

Use [`_.some()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#some) to check if there's an item with the `groupId` inside the `myItems` property. If `_.some()` returns `true`, the item would be included in the result.

```js
const myArray = [{"myItems":[{"id":1,"group":{"groupId":33}},{"id":2,"group":{"groupId":44}}]},{"myItems":[{"id":1,"group":{"groupId":55}}]}]

const result = _.filter(myArray, o => 
  _.some(o.myItems, ['group.groupId', 44])
)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```